# Parameters without name model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model like this:

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

and parameters in post action:

```
name='foo' (not attribute[name])
```

In Create action I can to create Attribute like this:

```
attribute=Attribute.new(:name => params[:name])
```

How tell rails parse every parameter like the model attribute?

```
attribute=Attribute.new(params[:attribute])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't fix the form to submit the param in the conventional way, you can do this in your controller by editing params before creation:

```
params[:attribute][:name] = params[:name]
attribute=Attribute.new(params[:attribute])
```

or if you had a lot of params all of which you want in attribute you could just use:

```
attribute=Attribute.new(Hash.new(:attribute => params))
```